# Not able to change directory in powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, cd

```
cd  C:\Users\Rupesh Kumar\Documents
```

There is a space between `"Rupesh Kumar"` which doesn't allow me to change the directory but it is working in CMD.

```
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Kumar\Desktop'.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd C:\Users\Rupesh Kumar\Desktop
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: This just says you are just starting with PowerShell, so, please be sure to spend the needed time leading it first, to limit / eliminate confusion, misconception, bad code, errors, etc... YouTube is your friend https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+file+and+folder+management as well as the tons of free no cost guidance, training available all over the web. Always use full PowerShell cmdlet / function names and parameters. Shorthand / aliases like you are using are fine for interactive stuff, but not scripts, and you are still bound by what PowerShell expects.

Answer (score 2):

In cmd [`cd`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) is an [internal command](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) that receives an optional `/D` option and then *treats the whole remaining command line as path*, therefore it accepts spaces in the paths even without quotes. Just run `cd /?` and you'll see

```
CHDIR command does not treat spaces as delimiters, so it is possible to
CD into a subdirectory name that contains a space without surrounding
the name with quotes.  For example:

    cd \winnt\profiles\username\programs\start menu
```

In powershell `cd` is just an alias to [`Set-Location`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location?view=powershell-6) which accepts various parameters, one of which is the path. You can't have raw spaces in a single argument like (almost) all other sane shells, therefore you must [quote it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1) or [escape the spaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7) like this

```
cd 'C:\Users\Rupesh Kumar\Documents'
cd "C:\Users\Rupesh Kumar\Documents"
cd C:\Users\Rupesh` Kumar\Documents
```

cmd and powershell are completely different shells, why do you expect them to behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

Please add single quotes for the `set-location` as directed above. As a coder I tend to avoid spaces if I can in everything I write in code. I opt for `_` or simply capitalize with no space